# How to strike-through or un-strike-through a region or line in org-mode?

Tags: org-mode

Given a region or line of text in org-mode I would like to call a function that either strikes-through the region or removes the strike-through of the region or line if strike-through is already present.

`C-c C-x C-f +` does not seem to do the trick, as for proper strike-through display in my org-mode version, each line must be wrapped with "+" individually.

How can I define a function that works like `comment-or-uncomment-region` for strike-through in org-mode?

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, you essentially want to add or remove a `+` at `region-beginning` and `region-end` when the region is active; and, for it to be a little smart as to whether `+` indicators are already present.  This does not need to be `org-mode` specific and can be done with just a few lines of code, but there may be an existing function.  Inasmuch as `org-mode` is under constant development, I tend not to answer a moving target ...  An `org-mode` guru familiar with the latest build and previous builds should be along shortly ...

Comment: @lawlist Yes, I agree, this does not need to be `org-mode` specific. However, it's important that each line in the region is enclosed by `+` as only then strike-through properly renders in `org-mode`.

Comment: @FelixZ.Hoffmann The implementation of `org-emphasize` is quite naive in orgmode 9.1.6. Please note that the line-wise strike-through version is also not working in all circumstances. It breaks headlines and tables within the region to be striken-through.

Answer (score 5):

If you're still looking for the solution,

I've made a partial solution for this

check this out (copied from
https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/45848/18252):

```
 (defun strike-through-for-org-mode ()
      (interactive)
      (beginning-of-line)  
      (save-excursion     
        (if (string-prefix-p "*" (thing-at-point 'line t))  
            (progn
              (setq go_char (string-match "[ ]" (thing-at-point 'line t)))  
              (forward-char (+ go_char 1))
              (insert "+")   
              (end-of-line)  
              (insert "+")   
              )
          (if (string-match "[^ ]" (thing-at-point 'line t))  
              (progn
                (setq go_char (string-match "[^ ]" (thing-at-point 'line t)))  
                (forward-char (+ go_char 2))  
                (insert "+")   
                (end-of-line)  
                (insert "+")  
                )
            (message "[-] Not Proper Position!")
            )
          )
        )
      )
```

---

```
(defun strike-through-for-org-mode-undo ()
  (interactive)
  (beginning-of-line) 
  (save-excursion     
    (if (string-match "[+]" (thing-at-point 'line t)) 
        (progn
          (setq go_char (string-match "[+]" (thing-at-point 'line t)))  
          (forward-char go_char) 
          (delete-char 1)  
          (end-of-line)
          (delete-char -1) 
          )
      (message "[-] Not Proper Position!")
      )
    )
    )
```

Answer (score 5):

For visitors who use Evil: you can use [the evil-surround minor mode](https://github.com/emacs-evil/evil-surround) to deal with various kinds of markup, including plus signs for strike-through. Evil makes it quite convenient to work on the level of the visual-mode selection, lines or words. (I'm handling one line at a time, so not sure yet if there's support for identical normal-mode operations on multiple lines.)

However, [to delete the plus-sign markers, you'll need to add them to Evil as text objects](https://github.com/emacs-evil/evil-surround/issues/141).

Answer (score 5):

This post asked the question long time ago, but as of today and speaking of org-mode version 9.5.4, the strikethrough feature has already been integrated into `org-emphasize` function. See <kbd>f1</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> `describe variable` and look for `org-emphasize-alist` you are going to see all the markings and strikethrough can be invoked by pressing <kbd>+</kbd> after the <kbd>C-c C-x C-f</kbd> keystroke (which invokes the `org-emphasize` function).