# org-mode: wrapping sentence with '+' symbol to strike-through easily seems not working

Tags: org-mode

I've known there's similar question [How to strike-through or un-strike-through a region or line in org-mode?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/36758/how-to-strike-through-or-un-strike-through-a-region-or-line-in-org-mode)

but no proper answer they've got yet.

I just wonder how to make wrapped word or sentence with strike-through easily in my org-mode

'*' '=' '_' symbols are working correctly with wrapped word or sentence but '+' not working which I want to use.

is there anyone who knows how to solve this problem?

Thank you!

Comment: Please specify your org-version. Word or line works OK for me in version 9.1.3, but not for a sentence longer than a line.

Comment: @Ian org-mode version which I'm using is 9.1.11 :-)

Comment: Please check the variable ```org-emphasis-alist```. This controls what is to be bold, italic, etc. Mine has also this: ```(:strike-through t) ``` .

Comment: @Ian That's right I checked `org-emphasis-alist` before but everything is working except for `+` keyword ;-/  and I just wrote 2 functions that can do strike-through automatically. Thank you for kind help anyway! :-)

Comment: Does your functions works for a sentence on  more lines or region? If yes, then you can write an answer for the link provided inside question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [wrap-region](https://github.com/rejeep/wrap-region.el) to add automatic wrapping to org-mode text characters, including the "+".

```
 (use-package wrap-region
    :ensure t
    :config
    (wrap-region-global-mode t)
    (wrap-region-add-wrapper "~" "~" nil 'org-mode)  ; code
    (wrap-region-add-wrapper "*" "*" nil 'org-mode)  ; bold
    (wrap-region-add-wrapper "/" "/" nil 'org-mode)  ; italic
    (wrap-region-add-wrapper "+" "+" nil 'org-mode)  ; strikethrough
    (wrap-region-add-wrapper "=" "=" nil 'org-mode)) ; verbatim
```

Comment: Oh! That seems like pretty useful package :-)  Thank you @Heikki

Answer (score 1):

You can use this function on a single line. put your cursor on a line, then use this function. (for only org-mode)

```
 (defun strike-through-for-org-mode ()
      (interactive)
      (beginning-of-line)  
      (save-excursion     
        (if (string-prefix-p "*" (thing-at-point 'line t))  
            (progn
              (setq go_char (string-match "[ ]" (thing-at-point 'line t)))  
              (forward-char (+ go_char 1))
              (insert "+")   
              (end-of-line)  
              (insert "+")   
              )
          (if (string-match "[^ ]" (thing-at-point 'line t))  
              (progn
                (setq go_char (string-match "[^ ]" (thing-at-point 'line t)))  
                (forward-char (+ go_char 2))  
                (insert "+")   
                (end-of-line)  
                (insert "+")  
                )
            (message "[-] Not Proper Position!")
            )
          )
        )
      )
```

---

```
(defun strike-through-for-org-mode-undo ()
  (interactive)
  (beginning-of-line) 
  (save-excursion     
    (if (string-match "[+]" (thing-at-point 'line t)) 
        (progn
          (setq go_char (string-match "[+]" (thing-at-point 'line t)))  
          (forward-char go_char) 
          (delete-char 1)  
          (end-of-line)
          (delete-char -1) 
          )
      (message "[-] Not Proper Position!")
      )
    )
    )
```

Comment: I've just written some simple functions which can do strike-through automatically in cursor line. hope it helps some people who need this feature